# Every uncountable compact uniform space has a nonatomic measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-spaces

It is known that    the class of nonatomic measures on compact metric space without isolated point  $X$ is  dense  in 
$\mathcal{M}(X)$, where $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the set of Borel probability measures endowed with the weak$^*$ topology.

In my research, $X$ is a compact uniform space. 
Is it true that the class of non-atomic measures on compact uniform $X$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

$X=\omega_1+1$ is an uncountable compact uniform space. I don't know of any non-atomic Borel measure defined on $X$. The standard Dieudonné measure is not. Ulam proved there cannot be a total non-atomic measure. So I think this $X$ will give you a counterexample.

Comment: In [Rao, Rao, "Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, \omega_1]$" (1971)] it is proven that on $X = \omega_1 + 1 = [0, \omega_1]$ there is no non-atomic Borel measure. Moreover, every finite positive Borel measure is of the form $c \mu + \tau$ where $\mu$ is the Dieudonné measure and $\tau$ is concentrated on a countable subset of $[0, \omega_1]$.